# If the difference of the function only dependent on the difference of input, can we say it's linear without assuming it's continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory, functions

As state in the title, if for a function $$f(t+\tau)-f(t)=R(\tau), \forall t,\tau$$
$R(\tau)$ is just a general function showing the difference has nothing to do with $t$.
then I can prove $f(t)=at+b$ where $a,b$ is some certain constant, if assuming $f$ continuous, I prove it by first proving it's true over rational number set.

However, is this also true even if we don't specify the function to be continuous but only measurable?

Comment: what is $R(\tau)$?

Comment: @gt6989b it's just a general function showing the result only dependent on $\tau$

Comment: It is true, because (stated [here]() without proof), "An additive real function is linear if and only if it is measurable, $\\$ so for every such [additive, non-linear] function there is a Vitali set.  $\\$ The construction of f relies on the axiom of choice." 
An "additive" function is one satisfying $f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$.

Comment: I think $R(\tau)$ has to be linear in $\tau$.  If $R(\tau) = \tau^2$, for example, then $f$ is not linear.

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese Can you construct a certain function where any $f(t_1)-f(t_2)=(t_1-t_2)^2$?

Comment: I think you mean to be concluding that $f$ is *affine*. Notice that $f(t) = at + b$ satisfies your condition.

Comment: @beedrill Yes, now that I think more about this, such an $R$ doesn't seem possible.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, measurability implies that $f$ is affine. Proof: Let $g(t) = f(t) - f(0)$. Then $g$ is additive, because $$ g(a + b) = f(a + b) - f(0) = f(a) + R(b) - f(0),$$ and $R(b) = f(0 + b) - f(0)$, so $g(a + b) = f(a) + f(b) - 2f(0) = g(a) + g(b)$. Furthermore, $g$ is measurable. Every additive, measurable function is linear (see e.g. Theorem 5.5 in Horst Herrlich's "Axiom of Choice".) Therefore, there is some $a$ so that $g(t) = at$ for all $t$, and hence $f(t) = at + f(0)$ for all $t$.